# Azure - Redeploy existing windows VMs in Azure to connect to Virtual Network

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I need to connect my existing VMs to new Virtual Network. Documentations says you have to redeploy them, but I could not find any source which says how to redeploy an existing VM.

Thanks,

Prasad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create an image of your VM**:

1. Select your VM
2. Hit Capture on the bottom bar. Give it a name and make sure it completes successfully
3. Navigate to Cloud Service >> Select the CS >> Delete >> Chose CS and it's deployments
4. Review the list of VMs and disks that are going to be deleted
5. Delete

**Redeploy the VM from Image**:

1. Click New >> Compute >> Virtual Machine >> From Gallery
2. On the right side >> Click My Images >> Select your captured image
3. Complete the wizard. Make sure to select the correct Virtual Network.

**Pre-requisites**:

1. Virtual Network is in the same location as the captured Image. Otherwise you will have to move the VHD to a storage located in the same data center as the new Virtual Network. Virtual Network will not show up on the list if this pre-requisite is not met.
2. If you intend to use the captured image to deploy several other VMs with the same content you will have to run sysprep (windows) or deprovision waagent (linux) before capturing. Otherwise you will have connectivity problems since all the vms will share the same unique Ids.

**More Info**:

How to Capture a Windows Virtual Machine to Use as a Template: 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-capture-image-windows-server/

How to Capture a Linux Virtual Machine to Use as a Template: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/

Comment: Thanks. So basically redeploy means, destroy the current VM by capturing an image and recreate the VM. In my case the current VMs are not special they were just created from gallery templates. BTW, using SysPrep path, I lost a VM where I had bunch of stuff installed and working. Thanks, This answers my question.

Comment: or keeping the VHD on delete. When you delete a VM you have the option to keep the VHDs. Basically instead of redeploying from image you redeploy from "My Disks". This option appears only when deleting the VM and not the CS. The CS you will have to manually delete later. Regarding sysprep, it never makes you lose data. Not sure what you did there. When you capture an image of a syspreped VM it will automatically delete the VM but the image will be available in the images tab.

Comment: Bruno: is it possible that something went wrong during the SysPrep or capture? I still have my Image, but I have tried twice to create a VM from it. The new VM gets stuck at provisioning state.

Comment: did you make sure to select the checkbox "generalize" and shutdown the vm before capturing? When you try to use an image that was not syspreped and you deploy more than one VM using the same base image, it might get stuck at provisioning due to conflicts of unique identifiers. My guess is that the agent responsible to exchange information between azure and the vm gets lost in this case. A few times i could RDP after waiting 3-4h. Not sure what happens inside during the provision phase. Maybe some service just timeouts and resets itself. See if that works for you.